# Where does OS X Lion save data from my iPhone backups?

Tags: macos, itunes

Where does OS X Lion save all the information it copies when making backups of my iPhone 4? Specifically, I'm looking for where my contacts, photos, music are.

I can not find them in the 'Application Support' folder.

Answer (score 2):

Information *about* your iPhone is in ~/Library/MobileDevice

The Backup of your iPhone (photos, documents, settings, etc.) is in ~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup

Neither of the above are in a form which is easily readable.

To be able to see and/or extract data from the backup you can use an application like [iBackup Viewer](http://www.imactools.com/iphonebackupviewer/)

Comment: I have looked the same path, but under Applocation Support I an not fined MobileSync/Backup.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget also about the mobile apps from your phone. When you do a phone backup from iTunes it also prompts you to back up all the mobile apps from your phone.

The apps are backed up separately and stored at the following directory: `~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Mobile Applications`

For Mac OS X 10.6 and earlier the location is: `~/Music/iTunes/Mobile Applications/`